# Import bitcoin address only with public key

Tags: blockchain.info, public-key, paper-wallet, watch-only

[image]

I want to import a none spendable paper wallet. This was possible in the past. But now I am only allowed to import an adress with the private key. So this address won´t be none spendable. Was there an update which changed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for watch only wallet, the Sentinel or BLuewallet watch-only would be the best option.

https://samouraiwallet.com/sentinel

https://bluewallet.io/watch-only/

They do import wallets based on the xpub(ypub/zpub). Blockchain.info in general is a very weak implementation with engineering flaws.